# Can BreadthFirstScan be modified?

Tags: functions, programming, graphs-and-networks, implementation-details, searching

I would like to obtain a "slick" implementation of A*-search algorithm on Graph objects, using the built-in BreadthFirstScan (if that is possible at all). I noticed that BreadthFirstScan is static in the sense that once a graph g is given to,

`BreadthFirstScan[g, StartNode, {"DiscoverVertex -> func}]`

'func' cannot alter g as need be and hence cannot run the course of the A*-search algorithm.

I know of one solution to A* algorithm on Mathematica.se, but it seems too verbose. Is it possible to use BreadthFirstScan? My rough guess is that it is not, but I want to confirm. To summarize my question is this: "Is there a way to make BreadthFirstScan alter its path?" I know that Throw can be used inside the execution of BreadthFirstScan, but it only jumps out of an "event" (e.g., "DiscoverVertex"), not alter the path of traversal for the graph.